# Why can't I "improve" a tag wiki edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, specific-edit

I just did an edit review for a tag wiki edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23960864

I rejected the edit, because I understood that the tag wiki should describe the project, not the reason the tag was created.

First I was astonished I could not **improve edit** on a tag wiki or tag wiki excerpt like any other edit. So I thought I'd go to the page of the tag and propose another edit, which is completely impossible for me. There are links to **edit pending** and **excerpt edit pending**, but when I click on them, I arrive at the proposed edits that I approved or rejected and that I cannot edit.

Comment: Note that both questions tagged with that tag are not about programming. Mentioning that it's only for programming questions in the excerpt might be a good step.

Comment: Also, the [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23960865) was copied verbatim from https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc and should have been rejected as it "copies a significant amount of content from an external source"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the FAQ [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284):

> We [stop accepting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled/81701#81701) for many reasons, including but not limited to:
>
> ...
>
> - There is a pending suggested edit to that particular post that has not been reviewed yet.

So far, you were the only one to review that suggested edit, so the edit is still pending and no other edit can be suggested until it was fully reviewed.

You need at least [20k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) to directly edit tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts. That's why you can't *improve* the suggested edit to the tag wiki excerpt yet. See this Meta Stack Exchange [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95520) and [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96233) for the reasoning (and waffles [adding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/95520/4) [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)).

Comment: Yes and it's a flaw in the system that people without full edit privileges are allowed to approve wiki tag edits.